# app:stackFromEnd = "true" doesnt work

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i try to show last item first in my ChatView. Unfortunately the         app:stackFromEnd = "true" function doesnt work and the view shows first items default. I did the following in my XML Layout:

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_above="@+id/sendlayout"
  android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

    android:id="@+id/recycleview"
    app:stackFromEnd = "true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager">
   </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Comment: Show the complete layout please.

Comment: stackfromend will only work in a ListView, post your code and i will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"` instead of just`app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"` and make sure you don't set it programatically as well:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycleview"
    app:stackFromEnd = "true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because LinearLayoutManager overrided the stackFromEnd setting, your have to set stackFromEnd in LinearLayoutManager:

```
recycleview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context).apply {
        orientation = LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL
        stackFromEnd = true
        // Apply other LinearLayoutManager settings
    }
```